# Maple Ubuntu anti-aliasing

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, antialiasing, maple

I use Maple 14 on Ubuntu 14. But it has some problems with fonts like this.

[image]

Do you have advises to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, font anti-aliasing is turned off for Linux.

To enable font anti-aliasing go to Tools - Options - Display and set "Font anti-aliasing" to "enabled".